# How to commit an offset on java flink with KafkaSource

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I want to processed the message from kafka and then to commit that message and once flink consume and process all Messages end the Job, to escalete the process with taskmanager and heartbeat

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment environment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    KafkaSource<String> source = KafkaSource.<String>builder()
            .setBootstrapServers(address)
            .setTopics(inputTopic)
            .setGroupId(consumerGroup)
            .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
            .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new SimpleStringSchema())
            .setProperty("enable.auto.commit", "true")
            .setProperty("commit.offsets.on.checkpoint", "true")
            .build();

    DataStream<String> stream = environment.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "Kafka Source");
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    stream.map((value) -> {
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your job to stop then you should set it as a batch job and not as a stream job. Here more info: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/execution_mode/.

As for commiting the records to kafka broker, it is done automatically by flink on every successful checkpoint/savepoint, so you do not have to do anything in that regard.

Comment: Thanks! the consumer an therefore the job finish but it still cannot commit 

        environment.setRuntimeMode(RuntimeExecutionMode.BATCH);
        environment.setParallelism(24);
        KafkaSource<String> source = KafkaSource.<String>builder()
                .setBounded(OffsetsInitializer.latest())
                .setBootstrapServers(address)
                .setTopics(inputTopic)
                .setGroupId(consumerGroup)
                .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
                .setDeserializer(new SimpleStringSchema())
                .build();

Comment: Have you set a checkpointing configuration?